# How to preserve Remember me when migrate fom Symfony 3 to 4?

Tags: symfony

I migrate my application from Symfony 3.4 to Symfony 4.2. 
When I deploy the application, the users that have a "Remember me"  cookie are disconnected.

The only things I change in the application at the security level are :

- Remove the option logout_on_user_change (which is depreciated)
- Add a directory in access_control

Is there a way to keep the users connected when the application move from Symfony 3 to Symfony 4 ?

Comment: for some reason i doubt symfony 4.2 uses the same kind of hashing as 3.4. besides that, i'd call this a non issue. ever pressed remember me on steam? this is pain.

Answer (score 0):

I was in version 3.4.8 and now in version 4.2.8, so it's may be cause by the modification of the `generateCookieHash(...)` function witch is modified as explain in this blog post :

[CVE-2019-10911: Add a separator in the remember me cookie hash](https://symfony.com/blog/cve-2019-10911-add-a-separator-in-the-remember-me-cookie-hash)